# Rename filename to another name

Tags: bash, unix

Really simple to explain :

How to rename

```
/folder1/something.test.html
/folder1/somethingElse.test.html
/folder2/againsomething.test.html
/canBeHereAlso.test.html
```

into

```
/folder1/something.test2.html
/folder1/somethingElse.test2.html
/folder2/againsomething.test2.html
/canBeHereAlso.test2.html
```

and also the inverse-function to be able to come back at the original point ?

This kind of things are really simple but unfortunately, completely impossible to Google them, unless you know already how to do it...

I was thinking about :

```
for NAME in */*.test.html; do mv $NAME $NAME2.html ; done # for A -> B

for NAME in */*.test2.html ; do mv $NAME #remove last caracter.html for B --> A
```

But unfortunately, it's not that simple...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simple string suffix and prefix manipulation, I suggest you familiarize yourself with the shell's standard [parameter expansion features](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) `${VAR%suffix_to_remove}` and `${VAR#prefix_to_remove}`.  These will work on any standard `sh`, not just `bash`:

*test -> test2*

```
for NAME in */*.test.html; do      # NAME is, e.g., "dir/foo.test.html"
  BASENAME=${NAME%.test.html}      # BASENAME is "dir/foo"
  mv "$NAME" "$BASENAME.test2.html";
done
```

*test2 -> test* is similar:

```
  ...
  BASENAME=${NAME%.test2.html}      # strip off .test2.html
  ...
```

You could also use the standard shell utilities [`basename`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html) and [`dirname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html) to achieve something similar.

Comment: Very beautiful answer perfectly what I wanted thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `rename` command.

```
rename 's/(.*)\./$12./' *.html
```

or

```
rename 's/.*\K\./2./' *.html
```

Comment: Thanks ;) and how to come back to the original state :/ ?

Comment: `rename 's/.*\K2\././' *.html`

Comment: What rename command is this?  I don't have it on all of my UNIX-like systems, and I don't have any rename utility that supports sed-like regex

Comment: It's a perl regex. All Ubuntu versions have this rename utility but I don't know about other distributions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
name1="/folder1/something.test.html"
name2="${name1/%.html/2.html}"
echo "$name2"
#mv "$name1" "$name2"
```

Output:

```
/folder1/something.test2.html
```

`.html` is being replaced with `2.html` at the end of the string.

To go back i.e `test2 -> test`:

```
name2="/folder1/something.test2.html"
name1="${name2/%2.html/.html}"
```

[See the Bash Manual for more info on Parameter Expansion.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: Thanks ;) and how to come back to the original state :/ ?

Comment: @ValentinMontmirail `name1="${name2/%2.html/.html}"` ... once you understand what's going on here coming back or forth should be easy i.e `.html` to `2.html` and `2.html` to `.html` replacement.