# Rename all files within a folder prefixed with foldername

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I have a bunch of directories each having multiple files.

```
dir1 
|- part1.txt 
|- part2.txt . . .

dir2 
|- part1.txt 
|- part2.txt . . .
```

I want to rename the internal files (`part1.txt` and so on) to something like (`dir1_part1.txt`). How can this be done in ubuntu?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343309/rename-filename-to-another-name) explains how suffix prefix can be added or removed. But how do I add a prefix as a **Directory Name**?

Comment: how do i get a directory list as a prefix?

Comment: Have you actually taken the time to learn basic shell scripting? If so, please show your attempted script. There are many different ways to get a directory name and the best way may depend on how you have written the rest of your script.

Comment: [`rename -v 's|([^/]*)/([^/]*)$|$1_$2|' */*`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/rename/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool called [`perl-rename`](http://man.he.net/man1/rename) sometimes called `rename`, not to be confused with [`rename` from util-linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html). This tool takes a perl expression and renames accordently:

```
perl-rename 's~/~_~' dir1/* dir2/*
```

The above will rename and move all files in `dir1` and `dir2` to the following:

```
dir1/file1 -> dir1_file1
dir1/file2 -> dir1_file2
dir1/file3 -> dir1_file3
```

[You can play with the regex online](https://ideone.com/d3JY71)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is a simple example.

```
$ mkdir dir{1..5}
$ touch dir{1..5}/part{1..5}.txt
# the command above create the files for testing
# then do the rename action
$ for f in dir*/*;do mv -v $f $(dirname $f)/$(dirname $f)_$(basename $f);done
```

Comment: eeee... [Don't parse ls or find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) At least not with a for loop.

Comment: ok, change to globbing

Comment: Please quote parameter expansions

Comment: All changed-ls-to-glob is of no use, if you use `echo $f` without quotes. :D You can simply use dirname & basename. Try to avoid `sed` for filename manipulations. At least use `sed -z` for such purpose.

Comment: @anishsane or: `"${f##*/}"` for basename and `"${f%/*}"` for dirname

Answer (score 1):

A simple `bash` script using `find` and [parameter-expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for finding the directory name.

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -name "*.csv" -type f -printf '%f\n' |
   while read -r x; do
       mv -v "$x" "${PWD##*/}_$x"
   done
```

**To handle files with special characters:-**

To handle file-names that  contain newlines or other types of white space or other special characters, am adopting `-print0` from `find` and reading them with a de-limiter `''`:-

Am using parameter-expansion again, to strip leading characters `./` from find command.

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -name "*.csv" -type f -print0 |
   while IFS= read -r -d '' x; do
       x="${x:2}"
       mv -v "$x" "${PWD##*/}_$x"
   done
```

A working example:-

```
[dude@csv_folder]$ ls *.csv
1.csv  2.csv  3.csv  4.csv

[dude@csv_folder]$ ./myScript.sh
`1.csv' -> `csv_folder_1.txt'
`2.csv' -> `csv_folder_2.txt'
`3.csv' -> `csv_folder_3.txt'
`4.csv' -> `csv_folder_4.txt'
```